# Custom dropdown values that map to a string in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am new to CloudFormation templates. I want to create a parameter with a dropdown that has values of "Small, "Medium" "Big". Upon selection, Small must map to "t2.micro", Medium to "t2.medium" and Big to "t2.large".

I know that I can have dropdown of values like "t2.micro" directly, but I want to have user friendly options that map to exact instance type string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Resources:
  MicroInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: ec2kp
      ImageId: ami-081c1b4c6y2d4594e
Parameters:
  InstanceType: 
    Description: 'Size of instance'
    Type: String
    Default: 'Small(Use for Dev)'
    AllowedValues: [Small(Use for Dev), Medium(Use For Test), Big(Use For Prod)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your best option will be using `Mappings`, you can have something like this

```
Parameters:
  InstanceType: 
    Description: 'Size of instance'
    Type: String
    Default: 'Small(Use for Dev)'
    AllowedValues: [Small(Use for Dev), Medium(Use For Test), Big(Use For Prod)]

Mappings:
  InstanceType:
    "Small(Use for Dev)":
      value: "t2.micro"
    "Medium(Use For Test)":
      value: "t2.medium"
    "Big(Use For Prod)":
      value: "t2.large"

Resources:
  MicroInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !FindInMap
        - InstanceType
        - !Ref InstanceType
        - value
      KeyName: ec2kp
      ImageId: ami-081c1b4c6y2d4594e
```

The key is to use the function `!FindInMap` that have the syntax `!FindInMap [ MapName, TopLevelKey, SecondLevelKey ]`

Some reference in [AWS CloudFormation Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) and [AWS CloudFormation Fn::FindInMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html)

Hope it helps